# Android: defining action bar style for a device running KitKat

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar, styles, android-4.4-kitkat

I am defining action bar styles for an Android device running 4.4.2. I've tested the styles on a device running 4.3 and they **work** prefectly. The phone running KitKat however refuses to apply any of the rules defined by the style. I've defined the same theme in all three folders: values, values-11 and values-14.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Setting values in the android namespace affects API levels 14+ -->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyStyledActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyStyledActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <!-- Setting values in the android namespace affects API levels 14+ -->
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/oc_actionbar_background</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/MyActionBarMenuText</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@style/MyActionBarMenuText</item>
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonOverFlow</item>
    <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTitleText" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#696969</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarMenuText" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">
    <item name="android:textColor">#696969</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionButtonOverFlow" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.Base.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_action_search</item>
</style>
```

I've also added

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

to the manifest application tag. But the styles are still not applied. I have however managed to change the action bar properties at runtime (changing the color), but that's not a desirable way of handling such problems.

If anyone could advise me on the matter, I would be most grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent these kind of issues, I like to use the following tool to generate the style for me: http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

Easy to use tool that generates the style just like I want it. Might help you too, since you avoid these issues. Just paste this in your project, and you're done.

Other tools can be found here: http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, works like a charm :) Will probably be using this tool from now on, since the automated process is unlikely to miss anything, that is necessary for the style to work.